# How can I render HTML in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, webgl, webvr, aframe

How can I render or display plain HTML markup as a texture in A-Frame?

I want to do something like:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<a-scene>
  <div>HELLO WORLD</div>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To render HTML as a texture in A-Frame, it is not as easy as dropping HTML into `<a-scene>`.

Solutions involve painting to a `<canvas>` and using the canvas as texture onto 3D meshes. The A-Frame community has shared some components for this:

- [HTML Texture Component](https://github.com/scenevr/htmltexture-component)
- [Draw Component](https://github.com/maxkrieger/aframe-draw-component)
- [DOM to Screenshot](https://github.com/cvan/dom2screenshot)